# Is there a legal requirement for US employers to have documented salary range for employee positions?

Tags: salary, employer

Pretty simple question that my Google-fu could not provide me with an answer.  I queried HR about the salary range for my position and was told there was none. I was curious about how this works.

Comment: Hello @Randoramma I think your question is unclear and somewhat broad. What is your goal here?

Comment: [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/896)

Comment: HR is not your friend. Glass Door is your friend.

Comment: @GrayCygnus.. Not sure how to make my question more clear.  Im not inquiring about asking for a reasonable salary for myself the tools available on the net are obvious and numerous.  I had heard that US employers were required to have a salary range for positions.. I couldn't find anything about such a requirement by googling and so wondered if there were any such requirements.. Obviously the breadth of US companies are vast but if there were any such regulation maybe someone would share their knowledge on the subject.  The Snark Knight answered my question if they are correct.

Comment: @Randoramma I am always correct.

Comment: Your google-fu should have at least turned up [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_compensation_in_the_United_States) which explains the wide variety of compensation means in the USA.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is a clear, simple question with a yes or no answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no such requirements for private employers. Public employment, however is a matter of public record and those pay scales are readily available.

Most labor laws are state specific.  Even the minimum wage is overridden by the states, but not OSHA regulations.  (States may have a higher minimum wage than the federal government.)

Comment: They can also have higher safety standards as well, contrary to your statement. States can almost always go above and beyond the federal government but never below, except though nullification which hasn't really been tried to the supreme court.